# How to unbind mouseenter (or hover)

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseenter, unbind

I have a "start"-button in a taskbar. Hovering over it displays further options (login, register, logout). I've also created a (simplified) JSFiddle for your convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/wF43d/4/

```
//1. bind mouseenter / mouseleave to imitate ".hover()":
$('#start').bind({
  mouseenter: function(e) 
          {//some other positioning code goes here
          $slider.show();
          },

  mouseleave: function(e) 
          {
          $slider.hide();
        }
 });
```

The problem is that I can't reach these further options with the mouse since as soon as I hover out of "start" the options disappear despite having used .unbind(), but obviously incorrectly:

```
$('#logout').on({
mouseenter: function(){
    $('#start').unbind(); //this is supposed to unbind 1. but it doesn't!!!
} //more code goes here
```

(code line 29 in the JSFiddle).

I know I could simply include the further options (".start_options") as a relatively positioned child element of the ".taskbar" and animate them to slide to the left out of the taskbar; however, this is prevented by the taskbar's "overflow-y: scroll;"-property, which for some reason also blocks "overflow-x".

So instead I positioned the further options absolutely and show them upon hovering over the "start"-button, but how do I prevent/unbind them from being hidden when hovering out ("mouseleave" in the JSFiddle) of "#start"?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to unbind anything, you can bind another hover to your slider and it works good

```
$('.start_options').bind({
    mouseleave: function () {
        var $start = $(this),
            startOffset = $start.offset();

        $slider = $('.start_options');
        $slider.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: startOffset.top,
            left: startOffset.left - ($slider.width()) + 10
        });

        $slider.hide();
    },

    mouseenter: function (e) {
        $slider.show();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wF43d/5/

Comment: from the jQuery docs: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call to .bind() occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event delegation in [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) or [.delegate()](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/).